# KeyEvent not firing when certain other keys are pressed

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I'm having more key problems in Java.
The <kbd>SPACE</kbd> Key event works just fine by itself, and when other keys are being pressed...

But if I press down the <kbd>UP</kbd> key and the <kbd>LEFT</kbd> key at the same time the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> event does not fire. However the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> does fire when if <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>UP</kbd> are pressed alone or with other keys.

Here's my code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        upkeyisdown = true;         
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        downkeyisdown = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        leftkeyisdown = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        rightkeyisdown = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        spacekeyisdown = true;
    }

}  
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        upkeyisdown = false;            
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        downkeyisdown = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        leftkeyisdown = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        rightkeyisdown = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        spacekeyisdown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyListener not being triggered after I swap JPanels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067906/keylistener-not-being-triggered-after-i-swap-jpanels) or [How can a KeyListener detect key combinations (e.g., ALT + 1 + 1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7851505/230513) or [Java KeyLister: How to perform an action when two keys are pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10655010/230513)

Comment: No, my problem is similar but those articles were not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [`KeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), there is no support for multiple simultaneous `KEY_PRESSED` or `KEY_RELEASED` events. The same applies to [`KeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html). You *can* bind to instances of `KeyStroke` that include modifiers, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513). Modifiers may include "alt, shift, control, meta, altGraph, or a combination thereof."

Addendum: "If I press down the <kbd>UP</kbd> key and the <kbd>LEFT</kbd> key at the same time, the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> event does not fire."

Using the `KeyEventDemo` from [*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), I see the expected `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events. The order varies because the events can't actually occur "at the same time," although `KEY_PRESSED` reliably precedes `KEY_RELEASED`. I suspect a logic error elsewhere in your code. One way to manage the complexity is to

- Use an `enum` to hold `keyCode`s; this [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) uses single keystrokes, but it illustrates how to use an an `enum` in this context.
- Use `EnumSet`s to contain recognized combinations; there's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559541/230513).

Comment: Well, by using the booleans I have a sort of multi-keypress system. This system works great, it's just being funky with the combo of UP, LEFT, and SPACE....but all other combos work.